# Desplazamiento a posición especifica usando bootstrap

Tags: scroll, bootstrap-5

Esta seria mi barra de navegación:

[image: navbar]

Lo que busco es que al presionar en experiencia, por ejemplo, me desplace de la siguiente forma

[image: ejemplo2]

Dejándome el titulo con borde superior.

En cambio me queda así:
[image: Ejemplo3]

Dejo mi código, hecho con bootstrap en angular:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
   <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" >
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white " aria-current="page" href="#home" >Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white "  href="#about-info">Acerca de mi</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#experience">Experiencia</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#education">Educación</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#skills">Habilidades</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#projects" >Proyectos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/agust%C3%ADn-avellaneda-9b392b192/" target="_blank"> <img src="../../../assets/linkedin.png" width="45px" id="logos"> </a>
  <a href="https://github.com/nitdraig" target="_blank"> <img src="../../../assets/github.png" width="45px" id="logos"> </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nitdraig/" target="_blank"> <img src="../../../assets/instagram.png" width="45px" id="logos"> </a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Log in</button>
</div>
```

Alguna idea, ayuda, o corrección que puedan contribuirme?
Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: osea quieres que el título esté encima del despegable? pásanos el código del desplegable.

Comment: Ese código tan solo es de la barra de navegación, y tu pregunta está relacionada con lo que ocurre al pulsar en alguno de sus items, pero no veo que hayas puesto lo que debe aparecer.  Aparte de eso, veo que usas **anclas** para enlazar a los contenidos, por lo tanto debes poner el ancla `#experience` en el elemento que contiene el título `Experiencia laboral` en lugar de la lista que aparece a continuación.

Comment: En realidad es simple, agrega un margin-top o padding-top al elemento que contiene el id de tu sección. Por favor añade un [example]

Answer (score 1):

Me sirvió agregar style="padding-top: 75px;" al elemento que contenía el id de la sección.
Quedando así:

```
<div class="row" id="experience" style="padding-top: 75px;">
  <h2 class="tittle">Experiencia laboral</h2>
```

Destaco que dependerá de la sección, los px van a aumentar o disminuir, Muchas gracias a todos por los comentarios y espero seguir mejorando. :)
Un saludo.